# Should :hover pseudo state style change work after CSS animation completes

Tags: css, animation, hover, css-animations

Should style changes specified on a pseudo state such as `:hover` work after a CSS animation has completed running on the element?

EDIT: Perhaps more pertinently, I should ask: why does applying 'forwards' on an animation prevent a more specific style change from overriding?

EDIT 2: Turns out that this is actually a cross browser issue. E.g. Chrome (I was running Version 38.0.2125.111) behaves incorrectly but Firefox handles it as per the specs.

Long story short: According to the specs (as quoted by chrona below) adding `!important` to the override should render the style. However, at present, only Firefox handles this correctly.

Here is a reduction:

```css
@keyframes go {
  0% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: pink;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes go {
  0% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: pink;
  }
}

.box {
  animation: go 3s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: go 3s forwards;
  
}

.box:hover {
    background: orange!important;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">Hover states don't work after animation</div>
```

I am unable to find information relating to this, nothing in the spec either: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/

Anybody know if a) this should be possible? b) how to make hover states work on an element once the animation ends?

Answer (score 11):

- a)

About why does it happen, I can't state for sure. But it obviously is related to the [**animation-fill-mode**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/#valuedef-forwards) property that you're setting to be `forwards`. That, by definition, sets the visual style of the element to be the last keyframe of the animation:

> **forwards**
>   After the animation ends (as determined by its animation-iteration-count), the animation will apply the property values for the time the animation ended.

[**MDN's definition**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) is a bit more clear:

> **forwards**
>   The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe encountered depends on the value of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count:

But I don't know why does it not allow the `:hover` state to override the styles.

- b)

Now, about how to make it work, you could remove the `forwards` property from the animation. In this case, you'd need to reverse the animation, so the original state of the element (when the animation ends, and removes the visual effect), is the color that you want it to be fixed:

```css
@keyframes go {
  0% {
    background: pink;
  }
  100% {
    background: green;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes go {
  0% {
    background: pink;
  }
  100% {
    background: green;
  }
}

.box {
  animation: go 2s;
  -webkit-animation: go 2s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  background: pink;
}

.box:hover {
    background: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">Hover states don't work after animation</div>
```

Comment: yes, the inability of :hover to override the value set by forward was the most curious part for me.

Comment: I'll hold of marking as the answer for a short while just in case somebody can unearth anything official for why the `forward` value prevents changes via `hover` working.

Comment: Aside: your modified snippet has a slightly different behavior on Firefox than the one in the question.  The background color hover effect works _during_ the animation in the question's version, but not until the animation ends in this version. _EDIT:_ This is addressed by a quote in chrona's answer, and is how it's supposed to work

Answer (score 6):

Quoted from the [CSS Animations Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animations)

> CSS Animations affect computed property values. During the execution of an animation, the computed value for a property is controlled by the animation. This overrides the value specified in the normal styling system. **Animations override all normal rules, but are overriden by !important rules**.

and a bit further down ([Animation Duration](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-duration)):

> […] and an animation that fills forwards will retain the value specified at the 100% keyframe, even if the animation was instantaneous. Also, animation events are still fired.

As you are animating the `background` it cannot be overriden by default (except for !important rules). If you don't want to use `!important` you should go by [LcSalazar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778434/should-hover-pseudo-state-style-change-work-after-css-animation-completes#answer-26778831). (Currently only Firefox reacts as described in the specs [6th Nov 2014])

```css
@keyframes go {
  0% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: pink;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes go {
  0% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: pink;
  }
}

.box {
  animation: go 3s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: go 3s forwards;
  
}

.box:hover {
    background: orange !important;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">Hover states don't work after animation</div>
```

Comment: but this is my issue – even when I applied `!important` to the hover state, it didn't work (e.g. like your example). However, I now realise this is a Chrome bug (I'm running Version 38.0.2125.111). When I tried in Firefox Aurora, it works as expected (as per spec)

Comment: Just noticed the same, it works in Firefox but not in IE, Chrome or Opera currently, I'll add this to my anwser

Answer (score 3):

Actually I don't really understand your question, may be you need the effects like this? http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/5td8w6jx/

```
@keyframes go {
    0% {
        background: green;
    }
    100% {
        background: pink;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes go {
    0% {
        background: green;
    }
    100% {
        background: pink;
    }
}


.box {
    animation: go 3s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: go 3s forwards;
}
.box:hover {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    background: orange;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

However, with these codes, when you mouseout the text, the animation will be replay.